# SQL Nested insert query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have today a database with 3 queries for statistics in testcases. I use php to build a website but the queries takes too long to execute, so I cannot show the complete site statistics as I wan't to do. As it is now the database is updated rarely in batches so I could make events that updates the databases daily / weekly for this purpose.

I have the following 3 queries today to display the information I want:

```
SELECT key FROM testcase GROUP BY key;
```

This gives me a list with int from 4-10 groups of tests. say 1,2,3,4 for the case of argument.
I then iterate this in the subqueries as key to get the number of tests passed and number of tests not passed with the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS passed FROM testcase INNER JOIN testcases ON 
  testcase.ID = testcases.testcaseid WHERE pass = 1 AND key = %value%;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed FROM testcase INNER JOIN testcases ON 
  testcase.ID = testcases.testcaseid WHERE pass = 0 AND key = %value%;
```

this is how it works today. The queries takes around 25-30 seconds for each key and that makes the site timeout. (%value% is pseudo code for the current value from the for loop)

Instead I was thinking of a sql query that added this to a database table that consists of key,pass,fail tables that i populate daily/weekly to show on the site as statistics. I have seen some cases where you can iterate with a subquery but as the 2 executed queries is opposites I cannot see any solution for this.

I have tried indexing the values I use in the queries with no success (which could be wrong as well).

// Andreas (SQL novice)

**Edit:**

Oh the dilemma, where to set the solution, I made a combine from Gordon and Joe to make the fastest query that worked like a charm:

```
INSERT INTO statistics (key,passed,failed)
  SELECT
    key,
    SUM(case when T.pass = 1 then T.matches else 0 end) as passed,
    SUM(case when T.pass = 0 then T.matches else 0 end) as failed
  FROM
    (SELECT
      key,pass,COUNT(*) AS matches
    FROM testcase INNER JOIN testcases ON
      testcase.ID = testcases.testcaseid
    GROUP BY key,pass)T
  GROUP BY key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do this all with one query, that returns the key and the information you want:

```
select key,
         SUM(case when pass = 1 AND key = %value% then 1 else 0 end) as passed,
         SUM(case when pass = 0 AND key = %value% then 1 else 0 end) as failed
from testcase INNER JOIN testcases ON 
      testcase.ID = testcases.testcaseid 
group by key
```

To the extent possible, you should let the database do the "iterations" and just read back the resulting data.

In response to your comment.  If you have a list of keys in $VALUE, then you could do:

```
insert into statistics(key, pass, fail)
    select key,
           SUM(case when pass = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as passed,
           SUM(case when pass = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as failed
    from testcase INNER JOIN testcases ON 
         testcase.ID = testcases.testcaseid 
    where concat(',', $VALUE, ',') like concat('%', key, '%')
    group by key
```

Or, if you are generating the query, you can put the list in an `in` clause.  So, the `where` could look like:

```
where key in (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: is it possible to insert the key in the %value% slot using the sql query? i'm thinking something along the lines of INSERT into statistcis (key,pass,fail) followed by that query.

Comment: hmm, The second one seems promising, but I get timeout in phpMyAdmin, gonna try on work tomorrow with mysqlquerybrowser and direct access. added the query _where key in (SELECT key FROM testcase GROUP BY key)_ and trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select key, pass, count(*) from testcase group by key, pass
```

An index on `pass` is going to be useless. Index on `key`, that should help a little. But with a cardinality of 4-10, meh, not going to be super helpful.

Comment: works quite nice to get the list, still a step from inserting it in a statistics table. I will see if I can get a better feedback using this query and iterate in php.